# Asp URL Rewrite on Multiple Domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I'm currently making a link shortening service on my hosting package. I'm using URL rewrites to do this. An example of this working is here - [dysign.co.uk/xBbYPL](http://www.dysign.co.uk/xBbYPL). This redirects you to Google.de. I'm using another domain mapped to a folder on my hosting package, so I have 2 sites on 1 hosting plan.

**freeyoutubedownloaders.co.uk** is mapped to **dysign.co.uk/freeyoutubedownloaders**. The link shortener is in the **freeyoutubedownloaders folder** therefore [dysign.co.uk/freeyoutubedownloaders/xBbYPL](http://dysign.co.uk/freeyoutubedownloaders/xBbYPL) works perfectly fine but if you go to [freeyoutubedownloaders.co.uk/xBbYPL](http://freeyoutubedownloaders.co.uk/xBbYPL) then you get a 404 file not found error.

Here's my rewrite rule in my web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Links">
            <match url="^X.{5,5}$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="Link.aspx?id={R:0}" />
         </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I've also turned on detailed httpErrors if anyone wants to have a look for me.

Lastly I noticed on the error screen it says:

```
Requested URL   http://freeyoutubedownloaders.co.uk:80/freeyoutubedownloaders/xBbYPL
```

Why is it referring to the domain and then the folder? The [Link.aspx](http://freeyoutubedownloaders.co.uk/Link.aspx) page loads fine... (To test it, add ?id=xBbYPL to the end for it to redirect you.)

Ps. I'm not able to access IIS at all due to it being hosted on 123-reg.co.uk

Thanks again! :)

Error:
[image]

Comment: How is it possible that [dysign.co.uk/xBbYPL](http://dysign.co.uk/xBbYPL) is working if the shortening service is in the subdirectory `/freeyoutubedownloaders`? Is there possibly another rewrite rules doing that?  In what folder is this `web.config` stored?

Comment: There's 2 webconfigs, one in the root of dysign.co.uk and one in the subdirectory, both exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling that the domain name `freeyoutubedownloaders.co.uk` has been added as an additional binding to the same website as `dysign.co.uk`. And somehow (I don't know how 123reg is setting this up usually) request for `freeyoutubedownloaders.co.uk/<something>` get rewritten to `/freeyoutubedownloaders/<something>`. Or they have set up some kind of reverse proxy for it without you knowing it.

When I test this on IIS 7.5 by setting up one website for `dysign.co.uk` and a separate website for `freeyoutubedownloaders.co.uk` pointing to the `/freeyoutubedownloaders` directory in the root directory of where `dysign.co.uk` is pointing to, it all works as expected. So I don't think there is anything wrong with your thinking on how you want this to work but I think 123reg has done something unusual in the way it binds the domain names to your site(s).

Comment: Darn, I was thinking this might of been the issue with the domain and hosting since dysign.co.uk/freeyoutubedownloaders/xBbYPL works fine. Might have to do it as a custom 404 page instead, and I may as well put a bounty on here in case anyone else has any more idea. Thanks.

Comment: You have to find out how 123reg is setting up the multiple domain names and why the request URL shows up as `http://freeyoutubedownloaders.co.uk:80/freeyoutubedownloaders/xBbYPL`. Maybe contact their support department and let them explain that.